# how to run dolibarr (through apache server) on AWS?

Tags: ssh, apache-http-server, webserver, amazon-web-services, lynx

In the context of [running web apps on AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html).

How can I find the admin credentials and reset the password for [dolibarr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolibarr)?

```
thufir@aws:$ 
thufir@aws:$ lynx localhost/dolibarr -dump
   #[1]Home [2]GNU General Public License

                               Dolibarr 3.5.8

   Login    _______________
   Password _______________
   Logo
   Connection

            [3](Password forgotten ? - [4]Need help or support ?)

References

   1. http://localhost/dolibarr
   2. http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html#SEC1
   3. http://localhost/dolibarr/user/passwordforgotten.php
   4. http://localhost/dolibarr/support/index.php
thufir@aws:$ 
thufir@aws:$ lynx http://localhost/dolibarr/user/passwordforgotten.php -dump
   #[1]Home [2]GNU General Public License

                               Dolibarr 3.5.8

   Login _______________
   Security code
   ______ [antispamimage.php] [3]Refresh
   Logo
   Regenerate and send password

                           [4](Back to login page)

   This form allows you to request a new password. It will be send to your
                               email address.
      Change will be effective only after clicking on confirmation link
                             inside this email.
                      Check your email reader software.

References

   1. http://localhost/dolibarr
   2. http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html#SEC1
   3. http://localhost/dolibarr/user/passwordforgotten.php
   4. http://localhost/dolibarr/index.php
thufir@aws:$
```

How can I configure the AWS instance so that I can browse to the EIP (Elastic IP address) and reset the password through the browser?

I can `ssh` and login to `MySQL`, if required, to reset the password.  I know that dolibarr uses `PHP`, I think the web server is Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how dolibarr works but from your question I see that you can access it from `http://localhost/dolibarr/user/passwordforgotten.php` and I guess this is restricted and you cannot access it with the IP address of that instance.

And since you have ssh access, I would suggest that you set port forwarding on putty for port 80. This can be accomplished by doing the following:

1. Open Putty and put public IP address or DNS of your instance into your Session -> Host Name (or IP address) field
2. Click the + sign next to SSH then click on Auth and browse to the location of your PPK file
3. Now click on Tunnels (still under SSH).

   - For **Source port** type **80**
   - For **Destination** type **localhost:80**
   - Click **Add**
   - Then Click Open and accept the security alert
   - Keep this session open
4. Now go to your browser and type that URL:  `http://localhost/dolibarr/user/passwordforgotten.php`